# How to display an image from a path in asp.net MVC 4 and Razor view? with url in link file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, view, model

i have some error object type 
 foreach (var Product in Model)
    {

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">

        <a class="ProductTemplate" href="../Products/@Product.ProductsCategory.Name.Trim().Replace(" ", "")/@Product.ProductsSubCategory.Name.Trim().Replace(" ", "")/@Product.id" title="@Product.Title">

            <img src="@ViewBag.UploadedImages.ToString()+".."+/@Product.ProductsImages.Where(x => x.isDP == true).FirstOrDefault().ThumbPath" />

        </a>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and incomplete. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: foreach (var Product in Model)
    {

        <div class="col-sm-3">

            <a class="ProductTemplate" href="../Products/@Product.ProductsCategory.Name.Trim().Replace(" ", "")/@Product.ProductsSubCategory.Name.Trim().Replace(" ", "")/@Product.id" title="@Product.Title">

                <img src="@ViewBag.UploadedImages.ToString()+".."+/@Product.ProductsImages.Where(x => x.isDP == true).FirstOrDefault().ThumbPath" />

            </a>

        </div>
    }